# Simple IIS url-rewite not working

Tags: windows-10, iis, url-rewriting

I installed the URL Rewrite module, I got the URL Rewrite option in IIS manager, but I cannot get even the simplest thing working!

I have this simple rule

```
<rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="TR" >
          <match url="throneroom/(.*)" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="throneroom.aspx?uid={r:1}" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

but accessing http://localhost/throneroom/ddd gives me

```
HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
```

It is as the url write was not working at all. I tried many things, inculding editing the web.config manually, or using the URL Rewrite rule builder, and nothing.